# Application of Ramsey Numbers

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

The definition of Ramsey numbers is the following:

Let $R(a,b)$ be a positive number such that every graph of order at least $R(a,b)$ contains either a clique on $a$ vertices or a stable set on $b$ vertices.

I am working on some extension of Ramsey Numbers. While the study has some theoretical interest, it would be important to know the motivation of these numbers. More specifically I am wondering the (theoretical or practical) applications of Ramsey numbers. For instance, are there any solution methodology for a real life problem that uses Ramsey numbers? Or similarly, are there any proofs of some theorems based on Ramsey numbers?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- [Applications of Ramsey theory to CS](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/ramsey/ramsey.html), Gasarch

Comment: Course in Ramsey Theory and Its "Applications" taught by Gasarch in Spring 2013: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/858/S13/S13.html

Comment: both urls 404 now =(

Comment: @vzn http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/ramsey/ramsey.html

Comment: re the class notes by apon link in comment. it is currently listed/broken also on [this UMD class pg](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/) listing classes. maybe moved to [here](https://www.myedu.com/University-of-Maryland-College-Park/CMSC-858R-Advanced-Topics-In-Theory-Of-Computing-ramsey-Theory-And-Its-applications-/course/4734305/)?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to above, [Ramsey theory apps by Rosta](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS13) (Electronic Journal of Combinatorics) also seems to have interesting notes on applications of Ramsey Numbers.  Also, I can perceive applications to Genetic Algorithms.